# MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy hangs after starting GRPC server

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, distributed-computing, hpc, slurm

I am trying to train my model in a distributed fashion with multiple nodes using a SLURM cluster in an HPC environment.
Therefore, I would like to use the [`MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy), in conjonction with the [`SlurmClusterResolver`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute/cluster_resolver/SlurmClusterResolver).

My current example looks like the following:

```py
# all taken from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional
import click


@click.command()
def train_dense_model_click():
    return train_dense_model(batch_size=64)


def train_dense_model(batch_size):
    # limit imports oustide the call to the function, in order to launch quickly
    # when using dask
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras import layers
    # model building
    tf.keras.backend.clear_session()  # For easy reset of notebook state.

    print('Trying to resolve cluster')
    slurm_resolver = tf.distribute.cluster_resolver.SlurmClusterResolver()
    print('Resolved cluster')
    mirrored_strategy = tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy(cluster_resolver=slurm_resolver)
    print('Number of replicas:', mirrored_strategy.num_replicas_in_sync)
    with mirrored_strategy.scope():
        inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name='img')
        x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(inputs)
        x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
        outputs = layers.Dense(10)(x)

        model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name='mnist_model')

        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                      optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
                      metrics=['accuracy'])

    # training and inference
    # network is not reachable, so we use random data
    x_train = tf.random.normal((60000, 784), dtype='float32')
    x_test = tf.random.normal((10000, 784), dtype='float32')
    y_train = tf.random.uniform((60000,), minval=0, maxval=10, dtype='int32')
    y_test = tf.random.uniform((10000,), minval=0, maxval=10, dtype='int32')


    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        epochs=5,
                        validation_split=0.2)
    test_scores = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)
    print('Test loss:', test_scores[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', test_scores[1])
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train_dense_model_click()
```

And the SLURM file would be something like (of course to change function of your HPC setup):

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=mnist_tf_distributed     # job name
#SBATCH --nodes=2                 # number of nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=1         # number of MPI task per node
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:4                # number of GPUs per node
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=40          # since nodes have 40 cpus
#SBATCH --hint=nomultithread         # we get physical cores not logical
#SBATCH --distribution=block:block  # distribution, might be better to have contiguous blocks
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00             # job length
#SBATCH --output=mnist_tf_distr_log_%j.out  # std out
#SBATCH --error=mnist_tf_distr_log_%j.out   # std err
#SBATCH --exclusive                 # we reserve the entire node for our job
#SBATCH --qos=qos_gpu-dev         # we are submitting a test job
#SBATCH -A changeme@gpu

set -x
cd ${SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR}

module purge
module load tensorflow-gpu/py3/2.4.0

srun python ./mnist_example.py
```

With one node, the example works perfectly.
With 2, the `MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()` hangs after the creation of the GRPC server.
Here is what the logs typically look like:

```
2021-02-05 08:05:36.232337: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:36.316739: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
trying to resolve slurm
Resolved cluster correctly
2021-02-05 08:05:38.271679: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-05 08:05:38.272752: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
trying to resolve slurm
Resolved cluster correctly
2021-02-05 08:05:38.317071: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-05 08:05:38.318107: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-02-05 08:05:38.404661: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.405934: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.407142: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.408221: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:8a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.408248: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:38.411154: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.411215: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.414114: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.414582: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.417932: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.419439: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.419683: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-05 08:05:38.429224: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2021-02-05 08:05:38.429943: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-05 08:05:38.451365: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.452604: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.453807: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.455016: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:8a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.455040: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:38.458031: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.458089: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.460714: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.461161: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.464314: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.465804: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.466032: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-05 08:05:38.475368: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2021-02-05 08:05:38.475996: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  SSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 AVX512F FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-05 08:05:38.862790: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.864062: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.865256: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866445: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:8a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866475: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866513: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866528: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866539: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866551: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866562: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866573: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.866585: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-05 08:05:38.874701: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2021-02-05 08:05:38.874745: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:38.913448: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.914700: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.915899: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.916981: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:8a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917005: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917034: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917046: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917056: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917065: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917075: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917085: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:38.917095: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-05 08:05:38.925980: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2021-02-05 08:05:38.926020: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:40.960412: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-05 08:05:40.960459: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 1 2 3 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.960479: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N Y Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.960484: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 1:   Y N Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.960489: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 2:   Y Y N Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.960494: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 3:   Y Y Y N 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.967901: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:40.970660: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1c:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:40.973167: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:40.975730: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:8a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:40.975944: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-05 08:05:40.976040: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
2021-02-05 08:05:40.977699: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:40.978891: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:40.980061: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981228: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:8a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981253: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981288: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981302: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981313: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981324: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981336: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981347: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:40.981359: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-05 08:05:40.990608: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2021-02-05 08:05:40.990663: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-05 08:05:40.990672: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 1 2 3 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.990678: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N Y Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.990683: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 1:   Y N Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.990687: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 2:   Y Y N Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.990692: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 3:   Y Y Y N 
2021-02-05 08:05:40.996569: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:40.997753: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1c:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:40.998941: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.000116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:8a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.000133: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-05 08:05:41.009003: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:301] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> r10i0n1:10002, 1 -> r10i0n2:10002}
2021-02-05 08:05:41.011782: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:411] Started server with target: grpc://r10i0n1:10002
2021-02-05 08:05:41.017706: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-05 08:05:41.017746: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 1 2 3 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.017764: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N Y Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.017770: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 1:   Y N Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.017774: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 2:   Y Y N Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.017779: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 3:   Y Y Y N 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.025119: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.027845: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1c:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.030414: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:2 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.032995: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:3 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:8a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.033204: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-05 08:05:41.033284: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
2021-02-05 08:05:41.034875: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:41.035945: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 1 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:1c:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:41.037116: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 2 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:88:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038281: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 3 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:8a:00.0 name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB computeCapability: 7.0
coreClock: 1.53GHz coreCount: 80 deviceMemorySize: 15.78GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 836.37GiB/s
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038300: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.2
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038328: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038340: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038349: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038359: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038369: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038379: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10
2021-02-05 08:05:41.038389: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-02-05 08:05:41.047551: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1862] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1, 2, 3
2021-02-05 08:05:41.047602: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-02-05 08:05:41.047611: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 1 2 3 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.047616: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N Y Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.047621: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 1:   Y N Y Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.047626: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 2:   Y Y N Y 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.047631: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 3:   Y Y Y N 
2021-02-05 08:05:41.053491: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:GPU:0 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.054675: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:GPU:1 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:1c:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.055849: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:GPU:2 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 2, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:88:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.057024: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1406] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:GPU:3 with 14759 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 3, name: Tesla V100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:8a:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)
2021-02-05 08:05:41.057041: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-02-05 08:05:41.065969: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:301] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> r10i0n1:10002, 1 -> r10i0n2:10002}
2021-02-05 08:05:41.068722: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:411] Started server with target: grpc://r10i0n2:10002
srun: Job step aborted: Waiting up to 62 seconds for job step to finish.
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 1877181 ON r10i0n1 CANCELLED AT 2021-02-05T08:15:56 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
slurmstepd: error: *** STEP 1877181.0 ON r10i0n1 CANCELLED AT 2021-02-05T08:15:56 DUE TO TIME LIMIT ***
```

I have no idea on how to debug this. So far I just tried changing the port for communication between workers, and reached out to the assist of the HPC, but I am clueless, so any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the reason was that there is a proxy being used on the worker.
In order for them to communicate between one another, you need to remove this proxy:

```
unset http_proxy https_proxy HTTP_PROXY HTTPS_PROXY
```

This solved my problem.